# Table with COLSPAN and ROWSPAN together?

Tags: tables, multirow, columns

I need help with my table. I need to (probably) mix row and colspan (see right bottom corner and 2 columns in the center) but i do not know how. Also I need more lines (questions) in 4th column - is another table good idea?

This is what I have:

[image]

My purpose looks like this:

[image]

And my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}                
\geometry{paper=a4paper,landscape,hmargin=28.5mm,vmargin=20mm} 

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}

  \begin{tabular}{
  | P{1.4cm}
  | M{1.4cm}
  | M{1.4cm}
  | P{7.6cm}
  | P{6.4cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{2.2cm}
  |
}
\hline
a & b & c & & d & e & f & g \tabularnewline
\hline

\rule{0cm}{1cm} & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
\rule{0cm}{1cm} & & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{P{2.8cm}}{\rule{0cm}{1cm}}  & & & & \multicolumn{3}{P{2.8cm}}{\rule{0cm}{1cm}}  \tabularnewline
\hline

\end{tabular}
```

I was trying a lot of combinations but latex is too hard for me and too complicated i mean... (beautiful HTML/CSS :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `multirow` and `\cline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,array}
\geometry{a4paper,landscape,hmargin=8.5mm,vmargin=20mm}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-\arrayrulewidth\relax}}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{
  | P{1.4cm}
  | M{1.4cm}
  | M{1.4cm}
  | P{7.6cm}
  | P{6.4cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{1.2cm}
  | P{2.2cm}
  |
}
\hline
a & b & c & & d & e & f & g &\\
\hline

\rule[-0.8cm]{0cm}{1cm} & & &
\multirow{3}{7.6cm}{%
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No \newline
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No \newline
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No \newline
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No \newline
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No \newline
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No \newline
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No \newline
Question \hfill $\bigcirc$ \strut  Yes  $\bigcirc$ No%  <--- % needed
}
  & & & & & \\
\cline{1-3}\cline{5-8}
\rule[-0.8cm]{0cm}{1cm} & & & & & & & & \\\cline{1-3}\cline{5-8}
\multicolumn{2}{|P{2.8cm}}{\rule{0cm}{1cm}}  & & & & \multicolumn{3}{P{2.8cm}}{\rule{0cm}{1cm}}  &\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But there is one more line over. If you look on 'My purpose' on right bottom corner looks like flipped 'L'

Comment: @Mark updated...

Comment: Now I noticed that the last column in first row should not be there... and also content "Question yes/no" should be entered vertical and horizontal...

Answer (score 1):

Because all cell widths are known you needn't to use tabular (nor `\halign`) because `\hbox to<given width>` is sufficient. I composed your table from parts and I used classical `\hbox`, `\vbox`, `\hrule` and `\vrule`. This is a basic exercise how TeX works with those elements.

```
\def\tabstrut{\lower6pt\vbox to20pt{}}
\def\tline#1#2#3#4{\hbox{\tabstrut
    \hbox to#1cm{\hss#2\hss}\vrule
    \hbox to#1cm{\hss#3\hss}\vrule
    \hbox to#1cm{\hss#4\hss}}\hrule}
\def\oline#1#2{\hbox to#1cm{\tabstrut\hss#2\hss}\hrule}
\def\ques{\hbox{\quad question\quad $\bigcirc$ yes\quad $\bigcirc$ no}}

\vbox{\hrule
\hbox{\vrule
   \vtop{\tline{1.4}{a}{b}{c}\tline{1.4}{d}{e}{f}\tline{1.4}{g}{h}{i}}\vrule
   \vtop{\oline{4.6}{j}\medskip\ques\ques\ques\ques\ques\ques\ques\medskip}\vrule
   \vtop{\oline{3.4}{k}}\vrule
   \vtop{\hbox{\vtop{\tline{1.2}{l}{m}{n}
                     \tline{1.2}{o}{p}{q}\tline{1.2}{r}{s}{t}}\vrule}}%
   \kern1.2cm
   \vrule
}\hrule
}
```

The result:

[image: tab]

I did change some partial widths (column j and k) because the global width of the table was greater than the A4 paper width.